# Dynamically creating collapsible lists without Jquery

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an HTML list of items dynamically but I cannot understand how to make the lists collapsible. Right now I only have a way to dynamically create list items. Also if anyone has suggestions for code optimization they are always welcome. I am limited to just Javascript and HTML though. Sample of what the list will look like. The data is very long so I would like to be able to minimize scriptlog's list item on click.

[image]

```
        var self = this;
        var nameItem = document.createElement("li");
        var dateItem = document.createElement("li");

        nameNode = document.createTextNode("Name: " + session.name);
        dateNode = document.createTextNode("Date: " + session.date);
        nameItem.appendChild(nameNode);
        dateItem.appendChild(dateNode);
        var element = document.getElementById("sessionData");
        element.appendChild(nameItem);
        element.appendChild(dateItem);

        session.actions.forEach(function(action, index) {
            console.log(action);

            var listItem = document.createElement("li");
            var node = document.createTextNode(action.name);
            var nestedUl = document.createElement("ul");
            var dataUl = document.createElement("ul");
            var scriptUl = document.createElement("ul");
            var versionUl = document.createElement("ul");

            var scriptLi = nestedUl.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
            var dataLi = nestedUl.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
            var versionLi = nestedUl.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
            var scriptInfo = scriptUl.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
            var dataInfo = dataUl.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));
            var versionInfo = versionUl.appendChild(document.createElement("li"));

            scriptLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(action.script));
            dataLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(action.data));
            versionLi.appendChild(document.createTextNode(action.version));
            scriptInfo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(action.scriptTxt));
            dataInfo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(action.dataTxt));
            versionInfo.appendChild(document.createTextNode(action.versionTxt));

            scriptLi.appendChild(scriptUl);
            dataLi.appendChild(dataUl);
            versionLi.appendChild(versionUl);
            listItem.appendChild(node);
            listItem.appendChild(nestedUl);

            var element = document.getElementById("actionData");
            element.appendChild(listItem);
        });
```

Comment: I think you will need to add some more detail if you want to attract good answers. What does the current code result in? Can you link us to a fiddle? What do you mean with "make the lists collapsible"?

Comment: @Anders Unfortunately the picture and description is all I could add due to the security of some of the data I am working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the `style.display` attribute of an element to show or hide it. As CDelaney noted, this can be done inside a click event listener.

If you already have the target `li` and `ul` elements in variables within a JavaScript closure, you can reference them directly from within the inline `addEventListener` function without needing to do any lookups to IDs or HTML properties.

Check out the example snippet below to see it in action.

```js
var source = {
  text: "1",
  items: [
      {text: "1A"}, 
      {text: "1B", items: [
          {text: "1B-i"}, 
          {text: "1B-ii"}, 
          {text: "1B-iii"}, 
          {text: "1B-iv", items: [
              {text:"1B-iv-a"},
              {text:"1B-iv-b"},
              {text:"1B-iv-c"}
          ]}
      ]}, 
      {text: "1C", items:[
          {text:"1C-i"},
          {text:"1C-ii"},
          {text:"1C-ii"}
      ]},
    { text: "1D"}]
};

var rootNode = document.getElementById("actionData");
createListFromObject(source, rootNode);

function createListFromObject(obj, element) {
  if (obj.text) { // add text node
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj.text));
    element.appendChild(li);
  }
  if (obj.items) { // add child list
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    element.appendChild(ul);
    if (li) {
      li.style.cursor = "pointer";
      li.style.color = "blue";
      li.style.textDecoration = "underline";
      // make clicking the text node toggle the child list's visibility:
      li.addEventListener("click", function() {
        ul.style.display = ul.style.display === "none" ? "inherit" : "none";
      });
    }
    for (var i = 0, len = obj.items.length; i < len; i++) {
      createListFromObject(obj.items[i], ul);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="actionData"></ul>
```

Comment: I was able to get the collapse to work. Using 

versionUl.addEventListener("click", function() {
     versionLi.style.display = !versionLi.style.display === '' ? 'none' : '';
    });

for specifically the version list item. However, I don't understand how to bring it back on second click.

Comment: The ternary condition is how you bring it back. It says if the display value is not set, set it to 'none' (to hide it), and if it's is already set, set it to empty ('', to show it). You need to put the click event on an element that does not get hidden (like the <li> tags, in my example).

Comment: @GenoDiaz like CDelaney mentioned, you're better off attaching the click handler to the preceding `li` tag instead of the `ul` element to be hidden; otherwise you're hiding the thing we need to click!

Comment: Awesome guys I got it to work. Thank you for all the help

Comment: @GenoDiaz Glad we could help! Don't forget to accept mine or CDelaney's answer so that people know your question is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to add a click event listener to your `<li>` tags and set the display to `'none'` for the child `<ul>` tags.

```
listItem.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var ul = document.getElementById('ul-' + action.name);
    ul.style.display = ul.style.display === '' ? 'none' : ''; 
});
```

[See plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1ozwW7CkYEPTwrk0axwf)

Comment: I get "Cannot read property 'style' of null"

Edit: I think its because the getelementbyid might need to be changed. One second